# Need background image to proportionally cover entire header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my background image cover my entire header in CSS, but only the top part of my image is showing when I use the "background-size: cover" feature of CSS.  How would I make my entire image show in the background of the header? Thanks in advance!

CSS:

```
header {
  background: url("file:///Users/FilePath/image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-style: ridge;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <title>My Page</title>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
   </header>
   <section>
     <p> My First Section </p>
   </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the image situation, but this might be the case that your image width is smaller than the width of the header, so when you do a "cover" it will stretch the image proportionately width/height to fill the header making it look like you only see the top portion of your image. See sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8ht837/

Comment: Your request is not possible unless the header always maintains the proportions of the image. Apparently that's not the case here.

Comment: try adding this:
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
html, body{margin:0; height:100%;}

header {
      height:100vh;
      background:url("file:///Users/FilePath/image.jpg") 50% / cover
    }
```

Comment: This accomplished precisely what I needed - covered the entire header and seemed to maintain the aspect ratio of the picture.  Thanks Amir!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a background-size: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments:

```
  background: #ccc url("http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50% 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ad8ht837/1/

Answer (score -1):

Did you try background-size:100% 100%; ?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Comment: Pretty sure background-size: 100% 100% is the solution to the question, but need clarity from mtaggart about what was intended. Either way, the link contains a great demo to find what is needed.

Comment: `contain` will not cover the entire header for most situations.